# C++ Passing variables to System() WINAPI ( No MFC)

Tags: c++, variables, formatting, system

This may be an obvious answer but I have little experience with C++. I am trying to pass a location of a files to system so that It will run it.

The code Im using:

```
        char test[20] = "C:\\";

        system("PAUSE & cd "+test[]+" & ping.text & PAUSE");
```

Which is not working. This is how I would do things in java really. How would I go about getting the character array test into that system string ? Any help or even a link to a possible solution would be a great help.

Comment: Even if there is an answer, I suggest that you check out the `string` class in C++, and/or `string.h` in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem using the following code:

```
        char testing[500];  // create char array
        strcpy (testing, "PAUSE & cd "); // copy the string into the char array
        strcat (testing, test); 
        strcat (testing, " & ping.text & PAUSE");
        system(testing);
```

As I am relatively inexperienced with C++, I am unsure if this is the 'best' way to go about things but It got my code working correctly without issues. If anyone has any information to add to this solution I will update this answer.

Comment: This code perfectly compiles on Windows -                          #include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
int main()
{
 
std::string test = "C:\\";
std::string command = "PAUSE & cd " + test + " & ping.text & PAUSE";
system(command.c_str());
 
return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

Raw character strings cannot be concatenated with `+`. Use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string test = "C:\\";
std::string command = "PAUSE & cd " + test + " & ping.text & PAUSE";
system(command.c_str());
```

Note that when passing the `std::string` to `system`, you need to call `c_str()` because `system()` expects a raw character string.

Comment: I am having some trouble with that code. The IDE is returning error `C2677: binary '+' : no global operator found which takes type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` along with 20 or so `could not deduce temple argument` errors

Comment: Hmm... the posted code works with GCC. Try `std::string command = std::string("PAUSE & cd") + test + std::string(" & ping.text & PAUSE");`